# Cyclic coordinate method: how does it differ from Hook & Jeeves and Rosenbrock?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, optimization, numerical-analysis

I have trouble understanding the cyclic coordinate method. How does it differ with the [Hook and Jeeves method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_search_%28optimization%29) and the [Rosenbrock method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_methods)?

From a past exam text:

> Describe the cyclic coordinate method and outline the similarities and the 
>   differences between the Cyclic Coordinate method, the Hooke and Jeeves 
>   method, and the Rosenbrock method.

I would appreciate a good reference, I'm having trouble finding any.

Comment: it seems like you need something like a numerical recipes book, or Bertekas's nonlinear optimization book